# Method of Class derived from template class "shadows" base class method

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual, shadowing

I have defined a class "B" inheriting from a Base abstract class "A" which has a pure virtual method:

A.h

```
template <class T> 
class A{

public:

    virtual bool doSomething(const T& data) = 0;

};
```

in B.h

```
class B : public A<int>{

public:

    bool doSomething(const int& data);   

};
```

I would have expected Eclipse to say B::doSomething "implements" A::doSomething
Instead the compiler says it B::doSomething "shadows" A::doSomething

Why?
How can I implement correctly the Base method in Derived class?

Thank you

Comment: Only a C++ compiler can fully understand C++ source code. Eclipse is not a C++ compiler.

Comment: Thanks ... so you mean the code is fine but Eclipse is wrong?

Comment: The only issue with the shown code is that "public class A<int>" is not valid C++; except for that there's nothing wrong with the shown code.

Comment: @ellysisland -- re: "... Eclipse is wrong"? No, he's just making a snarky point about the difference between an IDE and a compiler. Eclipse is an IDE; it uses a compiler to compile the code. He wants you to say what compiler you're using.

Comment: no error here: https://godbolt.org/z/K7od7sGT7. What compiler are you using? And please include the complete error message verbatim in the question

Comment: please do not remove includes from the code before posting here. It does not make the code simpler or easier to read, rather the opposite. On the other hand, you can place all code in one file and the response of the compiler should be the same

Comment: Use keyword "override" when you override virtual functions, it is easier to read and little typo or maintenance error will be rejected by compiler.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My IDE of choice is vim and it fully understands C++ code because it uses libclang behind the scenes. Many other IDEs do the same. Is libclang a compiler? If it is, your claim is meaningless. If it is not, it is false.

Comment: Aside: Eclipse is huge, clunky, and unfriendly, perhaps try some other IDEs out.

Comment: @n.m. libclang is C API that exposes facilities of syntax parsing of popular C++ compiler to application programmer. Eclipse CDT uses some kind of DOM parser that has nothing to do with compiling C++.

Comment: Any suggestion as alternative IDE? Thank u all